# Illustrator wrong CMYK color

Tags: adobe-illustrator, color, cmyk, swatches

I have a question according to CMYK colors in Adobe Illustrator. When I make a CMYK color in the swatches section with the value of C0 M0 Y0 K90, I get a brown-ish color, why? I want to make a black-ish color which is almost true black. How can I achieve that with the CMYK color palette?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is this only in a specific document or all?

Comment: This appears in every document I make.

Comment: What are your color settings? (do you have some weird profiles set or something?)

Comment: I took a screenshoot of my color settings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the working profiles you have set. Specifically "US Newsprint (SNAP 2007)", which (for reasons I'm not entirely sure of) makes blacks appear brown...

Set your profiles to something more reasonable.

RGB to "sRGB IEC61966-2.1"...

and CMYK to something like "FOGRA39" or "U.S. Web Coated (SWAP) v2", but that depends on where you are and your usual workflow and printing methods.

Comment: Great! It worked. I live in Europe so the FORGA 39 is the way to go I think. Thank you!